# Is it possible to have correct std::map with an std::list::iterator inside the class?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++17, stdmap, stdlist

In the private section of the class, I have this:

```
private:
    std::list<QTextCursor> m_cursorList;
    std::map<int, std::list<QTextCursor>::iterator> m_cursorMap;
```

And I have a function it does some magic:

```
void addCursor(QTextCursor cursor)
{
    if (cursor.isNull())
        return;
    
    QTextCursor c1 = cursor;

    const int pos = c1.position();
    qDebug() << " ";
    qDebug() << "pos" << pos;
    if (m_cursorMap.find(pos) != m_cursorMap.end()) {
        qDebug() << "erasing" << &(*m_cursorMap[pos]);
        qDebug() << "size before" << m_cursorList.size();
        const auto c2 = *m_cursorMap[pos];
        for (auto it = m_cursorList.begin(); it != m_cursorList.end(); ++it)
            qDebug() << "before erase" << &(*it);
        m_cursorList.erase(m_cursorMap[pos]);
        for (auto it = m_cursorList.begin(); it != m_cursorList.end(); ++it)
            qDebug() << "after erase" << &(*it);
        qDebug() << "size after" << m_cursorList.size();
        m_cursorMap.erase(pos);
    }

    const auto itc = m_cursorList.insert(m_cursorList.end(), c1);
    const auto itc2 = --m_cursorList.end();
    m_cursorMap[pos] = itc;
    qDebug() << "inserting" << &(*itc) << &(*itc2) << m_cursorList.size();
    for (auto it = m_cursorList.begin(); it != m_cursorList.end(); ++it)
        qDebug() << "after inserting" << &(*it);
}
```

log:

```
pos 0
inserting 0x55d774127fc0 0x55d774127fc0 1
after inserting 0x55d774127fc0
 
pos 0
erasing 0x55d774127fc0
size before 1
before erase 0x55d77408b4e0
after erase 0x55d77408b4e0
size after 0
inserting 0x55d774127fc0 0x55d774127fc0 1
after inserting 0x55d77408b4e0
after inserting 0x55d774127fc0
 
pos 0
erasing 0x55d774127fc0
size before 2
before erase 0x55d7740fd440
before erase 0x55d7740fd420
after erase 0x55d7740fd440
after erase 0x55d7740fd420
size after 1
inserting 0x55d774127fc0 0x55d774127fc0 2
after inserting 0x55d7740fd440
after inserting 0x55d7740fd420
after inserting 0x55d774127fc0
 
pos 317914
inserting 0x55d774bd0fa0 0x55d774bd0fa0 4
after inserting 0x55d774ba32e0
after inserting 0x55d774ba38c0
after inserting 0x55d774ba38e0
after inserting 0x55d774bd0fa0
 
pos 0
erasing 0x55d774127fc0
size before 4
before erase 0x55d77408b4e0
before erase 0x55d7740fcf40
before erase 0x55d7740fd520
before erase 0x55d774b9d4f0
```

And the problem with "m_cursorList.erase(m_cursorMap[pos]);". So when I try to delete the iterator, the size of the list stays the same. I've checked iterator addresses. And between several calls of the function iterators of m_cursorList become changed. So the iterator is valid and dereferenceable because the line "auto c2 = *m_cursorMap[pos];" works. But I can see that iterators are different between the two calls.
Could you tell me if it is normal behaviour or not? And are there any other ways to do so without iterators? I know that I can use set, list, and unordered_map. But I am still more curious about iterator stuff.

P.S. I double-checked the code and didn't do any other modifications with the list or map, which can cause iterator invalidation. This approach works for me when the map and the list are inside one function, but when I move it to the class level it causes some trouble.

Comment: `m_cursorList.erase(m_cursorMap[pos]);` immediately followed by `*m_cursorMap[pos]` quite obviously exhibits undefined behavior. You are dereferencing an iterator to an element you've just erased.

Comment: "when I try to delete the iterator, the size of the list stays the same." What makes you believe this? It cannot be observed in the code shown. For further assistance, prepare a [mcve]. My guess would be, you have still more undefined behavior in the code not shown.

Comment: "So the iterator is valid and dereferenceable because the line `auto c2 = *m_cursorMap[pos];` works." That doesn't prove anything. "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I change the line with logging. In my code it was alright, just didn't want to put all stuff here. Also, I added the output of the size after the erase. You, actually, could understand that size was the same even before. Because if the size was one and deletion was successful loop would print nothing. Ok, I will prepare MRE. So you think that in general this should work, don't you?

Comment: Yes, it can be made to work. One would just have to be careful about keeping `m_cursorList` and `m_cursorMap` in sync and ordering additions and removals just so. That said, I don't necessarily understand the point of the exercise. Couldn't you just have `std::map<int, QTextCursor>` ? What is the list for?

Comment: I can't have only a map. Because I need to merge cursors(map) and also have their order(list). So the idea is to have a list with data and a map only as a structure. Thank I will try to play around once more.

Comment: I tried to create MRE and it worked fine, but the same thing in the whole code structure doesn't work. Actually, It happened what I was afraid of.

Comment: So I simplified the code and add the logs. And in the end, I still have a crash in line "m_cursorList.erase(m_cursorMap[pos]);" and as you can see that the size is decreasing. But the number of iterators is bigger than 0 and became 4 in some place. Maybe there is some restriction upon a class which I can use inside std::list?

Comment: There must be some other piece of code that touches `m_cursorList`, and doesn't update `m_cursorMap` accordingly. The first `addCursor` call inserted a node at address `0x55d774127fc0`. On the next call, the map still believes there's a node at `0x55d774127fc0`, but the list no longer contains that node, but instead one at `0x55d77408b4e0`. The iterator in the map is already invalid, before `addCursor` even did anything.

Comment: Yes, it was my first suggestion but there are no such places. This is the problem. So maybe there is some hidden logic in containers that can cause this or whatever else.

Comment: If you just call `addCursor` with the same cursor twice in a row, do you observe similar (mis)behavior? I predict that `m_cursorList` will not magically change its contents between the calls. Look for other code that touches `m_cursorList`; despite your assurances to the contrary, there must be such code. "Once you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth." (Sherlock Holmes).

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you just look here for a clue. But I think I know the problem. The copy and move constructor etc. I should get it earlier I suppose. Thanks for your help!